# Parsing XML with optional attributes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a XML that looks something like this. Under the Loc tag there is an optional Residents tag:

```
create or replace temp table xml (col) as
select PARSE_XML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Locations>
    <Loc>
        <id>1</id>
        <Addr>123 10th street</Addr>
    </Loc>
    <Loc>
        <id>2</id>
        <Addr>456 11th street</Addr>
    </Loc>
    <Loc>
        <id>3</id>
        <Addr>789 12th street</Addr>
        <Residents>
            <Resident>
                <name>John</name>
            </Resident>
            <Resident>
                <name>Bob</name>
            </Resident>
        </Residents>
    </Loc>
</Locations>');
```

I want the result to look like this:

```
id addr            name
1  123 10th street null
2  456 11th street null
3  789 12th street John
3  789 12th street Bob
```

This is what I have so far. Because not all Locs have the Residents tag, ids "1" and "2" gets omitted from the results. Is there any way to rewrite the query to get my desired output?

```
select 
    loc.value
    ,residents.value
    ,resident.value
    
    ,xmlget(loc.value, 'id'):"$" "id"
    ,xmlget(loc.value, 'Addr'):"$" "Addr"
    ,xmlget(resident.value, 'name'):"$" "Name"
from xml
    ,lateral flatten(xml.col:"$") loc 
    ,lateral flatten(loc.value:"$") residents 
    ,lateral flatten(residents.value:"$") resident 
where 
    get(loc.value, '@') = 'Loc'
    and get(residents.value, '@') = 'Residents'
    and get(resident.value, '@') = 'Resident'
;
```